# T-SQL stored procedure: Select * From Where Value is not null

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a table with several columns.  I want a stored procedure that will filter a Select * statement  for each of those values if the parameter for those values is not null.  Would I have to write a like a sql server string or whatever, and if that parameter is not null, just append the parameter value to the string?  Or is there a simpler built in mechanism for that sort of thing?  I know you have to do the string thing for Oracle.  But ms sql server has always struck me as more user friendly.  I thought I would check first before I dove in.

Thanks

Comment: Are you filtering on exact value (`MyCol = 'asdf'`), or a search pattern (`MyCol like '%asdf%'`)?

Comment: I could go either way.  I think MyCol like '%asdf%' is the more likely route

Answer (score 5):

The easy route, assuming `col` is not nullable, or it is and you don't want NULL rows to match:

```
WHERE col LIKE COALESCE(@param, col)
-- or the longer version:
WHERE (col LIKE @param OR @param IS NULL)
```

(Where `@param` is either `NULL` or something like `'%asdf%'`.)

If `col` is nullable and you *do* want NULL rows to match, you could try this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(col, 'x') LIKE COALESCE(@param, col, 'x')
```

There are other ways to do it, as this could potentially lead to bad plans based on your parameterization settings and what parameters are used the first time it is cached (this can lead to poor plan choice due to "parameter sniffing"), but that is probably largely irrelevant here because your `WHERE` clause is going to force a table scan anyway.

A common alternative when plan quality becomes an issue is to use dynamic SQL, e.g.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 1 = 1';

IF @param IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @sql += ' AND col LIKE ''' + REPLACE(@param, '''', '''''') + '%''';
END
```

It can be helpful in cases like this to make sure the [`optimize for ad hoc workloads`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/) setting is enabled.

For information on parameter sniffing and dynamic SQL, see these posts by Erland Sommarskog:

http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: @dan if parameter is null it will use col value to do search on

Comment: @Dan Where are you see `LIKE NULL` Do you know how works `COALESCE`?

Comment: If NULL rows should *not* match, your first suggestion (either version) would work, wouldn't it? If there happened a NULL-valued `col`, it would not be LIKE either `@param` or `col`. Or I'm missing something.

Comment: @AndriyM You're right, the additional landing spot for COALESCE on each side should yield the ability to force NULLs to match.